# How to remove elements of a list containing specific patten with python?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, list

Given a list of strings

```
listA=['a', 'b', 'a@b=c', 'a @ b = c', 'a@ =b', 'a@=b' 'a=b@c', 'a@b' ]
                   ^         ^
```

we want elements marked in "^" removed, and get

```
ListB=['a', 'b', 'a@ =b', 'a@=b' 'a=b@c', 'a@b']
```

Here we removed all elements containing '@', followed by some character, then followed by '=', but ignored "@=" or '@ ='

How to do such regex matching for a python list?

EDIT:

I know if we know specific index of a elements to delete, we can use numpy.delete(list, index) to delete it. But it is not true in this case.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex searches in python can be done with the `re` module; specifically, `re.search('@\w=', my_string)` will not be `None` if `my_string` contains an `@` and a `=` separated by a member of `\w`, i.e. a word character (alphanumerics and `_`).

I've expanded this to include cases where there's whitespace too, using `\s`.

```
import re

listA = ['a', 'b', 'a@b=c', 'a @ b = c', 'a@ =b', 'a@=b' 'a=b@c', 'a@b' ]
listB = [a for a in listA if not re.search('@\s*\w+\s*=', a)]
```

*Update:* solution above now using `\w+`to match multiple word characters instead of just one.

Comment: Upvoted for being more terse and avoiding the use of `is None` like my answer (d'oh!).

Answer (score 3):

Using the expression [`@\s*\S\s*=`](https://regex101.com/r/gD8fU1/1) and [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) we can filter this list down:

```
import re
listB = [str for str in listA if re.search(r'@\s*\S\s*=', str) is None]

print listB
# ['a', 'b', 'a@ =b', 'a@=ba=b@c', 'a@b']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
listA = ['a', 'b', 'a@b=c', 'a @ b = c', 'a@ =b', 'a@=b' 'a=b@c', 'a@b' ]
print [x for x in listA if not re.search(r'@\s*[a-zA-Z]\s*=', x)]
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.